# $.when promise object not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, .when

I'm making concurrent AJAX requests but having an issue while trying to wait till all the calls have returned, console.log inside done() is showing result as an empty array. $.when isn't waiting for the requests to finish.

```
 var result = []
  var promise = []
  for (i=0;i < array.length;i++)
  {
    _url = "http://example.com"
      var req = $.ajax(
        {
          type: "GET",
          url: _url,
          success: function(request) { result.push(request)         
          } ,
          error: function(request) {  result.push("ERROR BROTHA")              
        }
        });
      promise.push(req)
  }

  $.when(promise).done(function(){
    console.log(result);
  });
```

Comment: ES6 solution:  `$.when(...promise).done();`

Comment: @MarcoScabbiolo: If you were using ES6, you'd write `Promise.all(promise).then(…)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to spread array. [Docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/).

```
$.when.apply($, promise).done(...);
```

From docs

> `jQuery.when( deferreds )`
>
> `deferreds` Zero or more Deferred objects, or plain JavaScript objects.